# how Create autohotkey to control pubg in mirroring android?

Tags: autohotkey

how to make script with autohotkey  to control pubg mobile with mirroring android

I tried this

But he did not work because I want more than one thing at the same time

```
    #MaxHotkeysPerInterval 100



     w::
      SendEvent {Click 306, 684, down}
      KeyWait, w
      SendEvent {click 304, 770, up}
      return 
      a::
      ; MouseClickDrag, left, 343, 783, 221, 784
      SendEvent {Click 343, 783, down}{click 221, 784 down}
      KeyWait, a
      SendEvent {click 304, 770 up}
      MouseMove, 304, 770
      return

      s::


 ; MouseClickDrag, left, 343, 783, 344, 905
  SendEvent {Click 343, 783, down}{click 344, 905 down}
      KeyWait, s
      SendEvent {click 304, 770 up}
      MouseMove, 304, 770
      return 

      d::
      ; MouseClickDrag, left, 343, 783, 465, 783
      SendEvent {Click 343, 783, down}{click 465, 783 down}
      KeyWait, d
      SendEvent {click 304, 770 up}
      MouseMove, 304, 770
      return 
      q::
      ;
      Send, {Control down}
      MouseClick, left, 1854, 560
      Send, {Control up}
      return
      e::
      ;
      Send, {Control down}
      MouseClick, left, 1662, 770
      Send, {Control up}
      return
```

Comment: The script seems to be functioning OK. Please explain what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Not fit to use more than one character

Comment: It is logical that it doesn't, all your shortcuts send a mouse click somewhere on the screen. What you need is to send mouse clicks at different coordinates but at the same time?

Comment: i use this with scrcpy mirriring  to play game    in scrcpy i cant control with keyboard i need  method To make keyboard do Touch on screen with scrcpy